# #Windows# Issue with tf2_ros::MessageFilter Tutorial on Windows

Tags: ros2, tutorial, windows, turtlesim, message-filters

I am a beginner with ROS 2 and I was following the [Using stamped datatypes with tf2_ros::MessageFilter tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Intermediate/Tf2/Using-Stamped-Datatypes-With-Tf2-Ros-MessageFilter.html) on a Windows machine. I have encountered an issue in the [3 Run](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Intermediate/Tf2/Using-Stamped-Datatypes-With-Tf2-Ros-MessageFilter.html#run) section. When I run `ros2 topic echo /turtle3/turtle_point_stamped` in terminal A and `ros2 run learning_tf2_cpp turtle_tf2_message_filter` in terminal B, I notice that the prompt in terminal B is blinking but there's no output. However, if I run `ros2 run learning_tf2_cpp turtle_tf2_message_filter` without executing `ros2 topic echo /turtle3/turtle_point_stamped`, it works as expected with output in the terminal. Any insights on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!